# Checking if CLLocationManager.location is nil

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer, cllocationmanager

I have a crash in my app when locationManager.location isn't initialized quite yet when I make my region to zoom.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    let regionToZoom = MKCoordinateRegionMake(locationManager.location.coordinate, MKCordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01))
    mkMapView.setRegion(regionToZoom, animated: true)
}
```

Originally I just wanted to do a simple infinite while loop like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    while (true) {
        if locationManager.location != nil {
            println("locationManager is ready, carrying on")
            let regionToZoom = MKCoordinateRegionMake(locationManager.location.coordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01))
            var timer:NSTimer? = nil
            break
        } else {
            println("locationManager is nil, waiting 2000ms")
            sleep(2)
    }
    ...
}
```

However then two things happened. The upcoming call to mkMapView.setRegion() complained about not being able to see regionToZoom, so I wasn't sure how to **properly** make it visible outside of the loop so I just put everything inside of the while loop. This worked.. However now I am reading that if at anytime I want to use sleep in Swift I probably should use NSTimer. Therefore I strummed up this:

```
var timer:NSTimer? = nil

override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2, target: self, selector: Selector("checkLOCMAN"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    let regionToZoom = MKCoordinateRegionMake(locationManager.location.coordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01))
    ...
}
// Function to check
func checkLOCMAN() {
        if locationManager.location != nil {
            println("locationManager.location is set, carrying on")
            self.timer?.invalidate()
        } else {
            println("locationManager.location is nil, waiting 2000ms")
    }
}
```

But this doesn't fix the problem, if locationManager is nil it still crashes. I think I am taking too much of a script approach to this, since it doesn't feel like that when it starts my NSTimer it is waiting but instead still continuing to execute lines of code thereafter.

Is there a way I can get this working? I simply want it to keep checking locationManager.location until it is initialized before running mkMapView.setRegion().

I am still new to Swift so I could possibly be overthinking this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not want to assume that the location manager will have a valid `location`. Nor do you want to have a `while` loop or a timer, waiting for it.

What you want to do is start location services in `viewDidLoad`, request permission for location services with `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` or `requestAlwaysAuthorization` (ensuring that the appropriate plist string for `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` or `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` keys have been set) and then wait for `didUpdateLocations` method of the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` to be called. Only then would you have a valid location.

Comment: Note, if supporting iOS7, too, you don't have to request authorization in those earlier versions, but you still need to start location services and await the location event.

Comment: Thank you, Rob! I followed your advice and it worked. I knew there had to have been a better way to do what I was doing.

Answer (score 1):

Your crash is probably happening because of this line:

```
let regionToZoom = MKCoordinateRegionMake(locationManager.location.coordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01))
```

since `locationManager.location.coordinate` is nil.

Although I 100% agree with Rob's answer from a style perspective and think you should put your `regionToZoom` line within `didUpdateLocations`, if you want to maintain your current code while avoiding the error, you could technically do this:

```
if locationManager.location != nil {
    let regionToZoom = MKCoordinateRegionMake(locationManager.location.coordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01))
} else {
    self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2, target: self, selector: Selector("checkLOCMAN"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew I was overdoing something. I moved my MKCoordinateRegionMake and subsequent region function calls to my didUpdateLocations and it's fixed! Thanks!